# How can I change touch rotation on Raspberry Pi 3 HDMI without X?

Tags: rotation, raspberry-pi3, display, hdmi

The display rotation (and the dsi touch rotation) is solved by `display_rotate=2` in the **/boot/config.txt**, but the hdmi touch device rotation does not happen.